# How to read a color of a pixel from texture (cocos2d-js)?

Tags: textures, sprites, cocos2d, ccsprite, cocos2d-x-js

How to read a color of a pixel at [x,y] from a texture (in cocos2d-js)?

Comment: What do you want to read? Its color? Its alpha? Its mood? Are you retrieving it offscreen, world coordinates, or screen coordinates? A lot more information is needed here.

Comment: Read its color. Question is updated. Pixel's mood is great.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not finding any way to do this within the cocos2d framework, so if someone can do that it would probably be a better answer.

However, cc.Texture2D does have a [getHtmlElementObj()](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.0/symbols/cc.Texture2D.html#getHtmlElementObj) function. Now, this function can return either an image element or a canvas element. If it returns an image, you need to make a canvas from it as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751659/1995101):

```js
var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

Once you have a canvas element, you should be able to get a pixel's color as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/667084/1995101):

```js
var data = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var color = new Color([data[0], data[1], data[2]]);
```

And just for good measure, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760522/1995101) is how to test if `getHtmlElementObj()` returns an image:

```js
function isImage(i) {
    return i instanceof HTMLImageElement;
}
```